# How to use python sockets to extract data from ipv6 UDP packets sent by different users?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have some small issues regarding python sockets.

I'm receiving some `ipv6 UDP` packets from different users to an interface called `tun0`. 
(In a raspberry pi) When I want to get the data from those packets how should I set the `UDP_address` and the `UDP_Port`? 
I know when it comes to sending data, I need to put the **server IP** and the **server port**.
I'm able to see those `UDP` packets through Wireshark.

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't expect us to write code for you. What have you tried already? How to write question:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did not ask someone to write me a code. I just have a confusion regarding what are the IPs I need to be set to handle data coming from many users.